# Issues installing the GMT package with Julia

Tags: julia, shared-libraries, ubuntu-18.04

I am aware that installing GMT with Julia only adds the wrapper. I have downloaded GMT and followed the directions from its git repository: https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/INSTALL.md.

GMT is installed and runs fine from my terminal. However whenever I try to use GMT in Julia I get the following message:

```
You don't seem to have GMT installed and I don't install it automatically,
so you will have to do it yourself.
https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/INSTALL.md#linux
```

This is a common problem where the solution is to show julia where my gmt library is. I did this by adding the following lines to my startup.jl:

```
using Libdl
push!(Libdl.DL_LOAD_PATH, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmt.so.5")
push!(Libdl.DL_LOAD_PATH, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmt.so.5.4.3")
```

I added both paths because I was not sure which one was the correct library (running gmt --version says its version 5.4.3)

However, when I load GMT I get the same message as before. Furthermore when I do `] test GMT`
I get the following error:

```
You don't seem to have GMT installed and I don't install it automatically,
so you will have to do it yourself.
https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/INSTALL.md#linux
5.4.3
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: GMT_Get_Version not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./Base.jl:26
 [2] top-level scope at /home/charper/.julia/packages/GMT/3tQ7w/test/runtests.jl:17
 [3] include(::String) at ./client.jl:439
 [4] top-level scope at none:6
in expression starting at /home/charper/.julia/packages/GMT/3tQ7w/test/runtests.jl:12
ERROR: Package GMT errored during testing
```

Finally when I trace that back to the file mentioned here are lines 12-17...I am not exactly sure what to do next.

```
using GMT
using Test

try
    run(`gmt --version`)    # Will fail if GMT is not installed.
    global got_it = true
catch
    @test 1 == 1            # Let tests pass for sake of not triggering a PkgEval failure
    global got_it = false
end

if (got_it)                 # Otherwise go straight to end

    const dbg2 = 3          # Either 2 or 3. 3 to test the used kwargs
    const dbg0 = 0          # With 0 prints only the non-consumed options. Set to -1 to ignore this Vd

    GMT.GMT_Get_Version();
    ma=[0];mi=[0];pa=[0];
    GMT.GMT_Get_Version(ma,mi,pa);
    API = GMT.GMT_Create_Session("GMT", 2, GMT.GMT_SESSION_NOEXIT + GMT.GMT_SESSION_EXTERNAL);
    GMT.GMT_Get_Ctrl(API);
```

Not sure what to do next, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should open issue in github: https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/GMT.jl/issues

Comment: thank you, I went head and created a post there

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question onto the GMT forums and we arrived at a solution:
https://forum.generic-mapping-tools.org/t/gmt-julia-and-ubuntu-v18/1270/9